# React Duplicated Name but different fields

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch-api, react-select

React Application I fetch JSON data from an API part of react-select:

```
import Select from "react-select";
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch"; 

return fetch(`some API localhost`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    return { options: json };
 })
```

Now option looks like below:

```
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": "Geometry"},
{"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"},
{"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Orders of Operation"},
{"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": "Geometry"},
```

and I want to combine the duplicate Grade and make it something like:

```
{"Grade": "Math K", "Domain": ["Counting & Cardinality", "Geometry"]},
{"Grade": "Math 1", "Domain": ["Counting & Cardinality" , "Geometry" , "Orders of Operation" ]}
```

how would I do it using react?

Comment: You tell me. We aren't here to write the code for you. Attempt it, let us know where you are struggling and show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a super complex problem. You need to think about, how to make the given input array values iterable.

Once you have a way to iterate, it becomes easier to apply, the transformation logic you have asked, like merging domains for a given Grade.

```js
const response = [{
    "Grade": "Math K",
    "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "Math K",
    "Domain": "Geometry"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "Math 1",
    "Domain": "Counting & Cardinality"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "Math 1",
    "Domain": "Orders of Operation"
  },
  {
    "Grade": "Math 1",
    "Domain": "Geometry"
  }
];
const output = {};

response.forEach((item) => {
  const grade = item.Grade;
  // Create a Map / Object to access a particular Grade easily
  output[grade] = output[grade] || {};
  output[grade].Grade = grade;
  output[grade].Domain = output[grade].Domain || [];
  output[grade].Domain.push(item.Domain);
})

const outputObj = Object.keys(output).map((item) => output[item]);

console.log(outputObj);
```